# Gradient background of submit button in IE

Tags: css

I am trying to add a gradient to a submit button in IE9 using the vendor specific CSS rule:

```
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#6671E8,#434991);
```

But for some reason this [doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/bYtdL/). Is it something I'm doing wrong or is IE9 screwing things up again (or a combination of both)?

Comment: I would use a bitmap/jpg/png.  It's faster, easier and cross-browser compliant.

Comment: @SteveWellens that wasn't my question :P

Comment: Or just be satisfied with a single color in IE9.

Comment: @PeeHaa - I know, that's why I made a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting filter to none:

```
input[type="submit"] { filter: none; }
```

I haven't confirmed this, but I read it on Colorzilla's gradient generator:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: If you click IE9 Support under the CSS code, it will say that filter need to be set to none.  But it also includes a Data URI scheme, so I'm not sure exactly which is required for it to work in IE9.

Comment: You are right. I thought the `ms-` prefix was for IE9, but it is for `IE10`.

Comment: There you go 3 more characters

Answer (score 1):

Use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) and set `-pie-background`:

```
-pie-background: linear-gradient(#6671E8, #434991);
```

Comment: It doesn't specifically answer his question.  I, however, found this answer very useful.  So, I will +1 you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
background: #6671e8; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #6671e8 1%, #434991 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#6671e8), color-stop(100%,#434991)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #6671e8 1%,#434991 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #6671e8 1%,#434991 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #6671e8 1%,#434991 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top,  #6671e8 1%,#434991 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6671e8', endColorstr='#434991',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```